# Sitecore Rocks - Add item in specific language

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-rocks

When I create an item in Sitecore, it will create a version in the selected language. In rocks, I always seem to get a version in the default language (en). Then I have to add a version in the language I want and remove the old language version which gets annoying fast.

So how can I choose the language I want in Sitecore Rocks, just like in the normal Sitecore backend ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You neeed to switch your language to a specific language an then create your items.

Select the item (right click) -> Tools->Switch Language (it's the last in context menu) -> Select Specific Language.

See attached picture:

[image]

Comment: Wow, that was easy. Thanks for the picture and the help

Comment: Welcome, anytime. I was afraid you have an older version of Rocks. It was a bug related to switch language until version 1.25